# How to Create another Page Category like the "Post" and "Pages"

Tags: posts, categories

I try to create a new "Post" kind of group that can be used as a different list to display different info. Someone already created two for us, but I don't know how. can someone teach me how? Thanks

[image]

Comment: These are called "Custom Post Types" The developer documentation for them is here: https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/post-types/, but if you search for them by that name you'll find lots of resources about creating them, including without code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Custom Post Type UI](https://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-post-type-ui/) to Create Custom Posts. It is very easy to use, there are many tutorials available.

Answer (score 0):

These are **custom post type** you can create by your own with help of this link -  https://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-create-custom-post-types-in-wordpress/